# Is There a Computer Application To Manage SMS Messages The Same as Nokia PC Suite Can?

Tags: applications, sms, htc-desire

In Nokia PC Suite we can backup mobile data (contacts, message etc) on a computer. We can also send, receive sms or manage sms by computer using Nokia PC Suite when a Nokia mobile is connected with a computer by Bluetooth or by data cable.

Is there any software or application by which I can use my HTC Desire SV mobile phone the same way as above?

I want to send or receive SMS by my laptop which is connected to my HTC Desire SV because this saves my time.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/downloads.php) to control (almost) any Android device. You can easily send and receive sms on your PC when this software is connected to your phone.

or [HTC Sync Manager](http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/) for synchronizing.

Comment: the software which you mention above only sync the data. You can not send SMS or receive SMS on computer while phone is connected by computer.

Comment: In MyExplorer every thing is there what I want ... Thanx dear

Answer (score 9):

For a system independent solution, you might want to take a look at e.g. [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid):

[image: AirDroid]

*AirDroid* runs as an app on your Android device. When you start this app, it offers you to start its service. Having done so, it displays an URL to connect to with a web browser, plus a password to authenticate. Doing so on your PC, you can manage your Android device from within the PC's web browser: edit your contacts, send SMS, play your media, change the background image, and much more. Even the clipboard can be shared.

Preferably this is done while both devices (the Android device and your PC) are connected to the same network, of course -- but you don't need a cable, as the name *AIRdroid* correctly indicates the "over-the-air" use of WiFi :)

Other than with the Nokia PC suite, *AirDroid* doesn't save a copy of the Android device's data on your PC. This is, however, AFAIK done by [MyPhoneExplorer Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) -- which was already mentioned in [MattLin's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38274/16575); but this is only available to Windows users.

Comment: thank you for your time and useful response. As you mention here this will work only when both device and phone use same network. Means phone is connected with WiFi which have same network to the computer. Suppose I don't have WiFi connection then this how this will work?

Comment: Via a proxy: Just visit the app's Playstore page, and take a look at the first screenshot. Alternatively to a local IP address, it mentions you can connect via `http://web.airdroid.com/`; all data will then be routed openly via the Internet (so I'd suggest to at least enable HTTPS in this case). Furthermore, your mobile provider has to support this (not all do, some block "incoming" traffic to your device) -- you may need to check this. But as the app is free, there's nothing to lose, right?

Answer (score 1):

[MightyText](http://mightytext.net/) - send and receive SMS from your computer. It will automatically get synced in your phone.

Comment: this is good application but it use mobile and computer Internet connection. I simply want to connect my mobile with computer using Bluetooth or data cable and start sending or receiving SMS. Exactly same as Nokia PC Suite.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Mighty Text](http://www.mevvy.com/tools/mightytext/) is the best app to send SMS from a computer to a phone. It makes the device suitable to send the SMS. Hope you will love this.